# Java reflection with unique id

Tags: java, reflection, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to build HashMap that its keys are unique id and the value is name of classes that found by reflection.

My problem is to create those unique ids. How can I be surly that each class have unique id, and it's id will never change to. I mean that if I will create new class it will never change the older class id.

**UPDATE**
I need that the id will be an integer number. (Sorry that I did not mentioned that :P )

Comment: Would the full path of the classname work? e.g java.lang.String for the built-in Strings?

Comment: What do you mean by `create new class it will never change the older class id`?

Comment: @RobWatts, there's the possibility that the full classname is insufficient in the presence of a modifiable classpath or multiple classloaders.

Comment: @oconnor0 For example to do a auto-increasment id and new class will found before older class

Comment: @Someone, how are you getting a new & old class with the same name?

Comment: But different strings can create same hash code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32102/discussion-between-oconnor0-and-someone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be guaranteed to be completely unique but just using the fully qualified class name should be sufficient.  The `String` name of the fully qualified path, like `java.lang.Math` would be a good "unqiue" id, and should very rarely have a hash collision.

Example

```
map.put(MyClass.class.toString(), MyClass.class);
```

EDIT: if you **need** it to be an int, you can always use the String hashcode

```
map.put(MyClass.class.toString().hashCode(), MyClass.class);
```

Comment: As I said it's not guaranteed, but I would venture a guess and say you would be hard pressed to find real classes that would conflict.  Also if you were very worried you could also use a MultiMap, or just make a Map<String, List<Class>> to resolve any potential hash conflicts.